# Differentiate between Microsoft Teams Groups from Office 365 Groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is that possible to uniquely identity groups that belong to Microsoft Teams from the result returned from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell if any specific group is also a team by using the url (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups). But you can get all the list of Teams joined by you using [Joined teams API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams).